# copy background color of first row

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, copy, background-color

Any idea on how id's have to implement the background colour of the first row (Headers) in my excel sheet?

```
XSSFWorkbook Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
ISheet DeliveryReportsSheet = Workbook.CreateSheet("Upcoming Schedules");
int rowCounter = 0;
IRow Headers = DeliveryReportsSheet.CreateRow(rowCounter);

Headers.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Resource ID");
Headers.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Schedule Name");
Headers.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Task Name");
Headers.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Next Trigger Date Launch");
```

Comment: The row and column headers?  Or, you want to copy the same fill colors from row 1 to row 2 etc??

Comment: Dude - you gotta read hwo to ask a question here.  Basically, it's the opposite of what you did.  I remove the question from the title but you need to add a LOT more information.  See [ask] amnd also [mcve] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Just the row and column headers only

Comment: I just want to make double-sure you're talking about Excel's row and column headers..  [**Click Here** to see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rscvs.png). **You just want to match that color?**

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to match the color of Excel's row & column headers (any anything else on your computer) is took take a screen shot and upload it to [ImageColorPicker.com](http://imagecolorpicker.com/), where you can click on a pixel of the image to determine the color.

[image: img]

Excel headings color varies by version.  The picture I included in Excel 2016/365, and the color is:

```
HTML: #E6E6E6
RGB: (230,230,230)
```